# Can I use “bereit” to mean “to prepare”?

Tags: word-usage

> I will prepare something to eat.

Is it correct to translate that sentence using:

> Ich werde bereit, etwas zu essen.

If so, how does the word *bereit* meaning *ready* become in effect the verb for *prepare*?

Comment: Your question is unclear (to me): do you mean you _get ready_ to eat something (like washing your hands etc.) or do you mean you want _to cook_ something (prepare food)?

Comment: No it is not. *Ich werde bereit, etwas zu essen* means *I will become ready to eat something*. *to prepare* means *(zu-/vor)bereiten* in German, so the word-by-word translation would be *Ich werde zubereiten etwas zu Essen* and due to the rules of German word order this would turn into *Ich werde etwas zu essen zubereiten*.

Answer (score 16):

You mixed up the verb **bereiten** (to prepare) and the adverb **bereit** (prepared, ready, willing).

> Ich werde etwas zu essen **bereiten**.

I will prepare something to eat.

There is also **zubereiten**, which is more common for preparing food and means the same in this sentence.

> Ich werde etwas zu essen **zubereiten**.

They aren't always interchangeable, however.

> Ich werde ihr eine Überraschung bereiten.

*I will cause/prepare her a surprise.*

BUT NOT

> <s>Ich werde ihr eine Überraschung **zu**bereiten.</s>

A third variant is **vorbereiten**, which literally means *to prepare*. It's also more common than simple *bereiten*.

> Ich werde mich vorbereiten.

I will prepare myself.

> Ich werde etwas zu essen vorbereiten.

I will prepare something to eat.

The difference to *bereiten* can be subtle. But *bereiten* is rarely used, you go well with *zubereiten* for food and *vorbereiten* for anything else.

---

Now the adverb **bereit**.

> Ich bin bereit, etwas zu essen.

*I am ready to eat something.*

*I am willing to eat something.*

Answer (score 1):

"Bereit" means "ready" or *prepared.* That is the adjectival form.

It is "bereiten," the verb form that means "to prepare."